If two nodes in a graph are symmetric, does there exist an automorphism that swaps their "location"?
Let's say that there exists a graph G. There exists an automorphism A that maps node n1 onto node n2. Does that imply there exists an automorphism that maps n1 onto n2 WHILE ALSO mapping n2 onto n1?

What have you tried?

Simple examples. Complete graphs. Trees. Every time I find 2 symmetric nodes, there exists some automorphism that swaps their position.

Frucht's theorem states that every finite group is the group of symmetries of a finite undirected graph. Take any graph whhose group of automorphisms is, say, the cyclic group of order three, and it will have an automorphism taking some vertex $u$ to some vertex $v$, and an automorphism taking $v$ to $u$, but no automorphism taking $u$ to $v$ and $v$ to $u$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht%27s_theorem#

Counterexample: Take the graph with $12$ vertices $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L$ and $15$ edges $AB,BC,CD,DE,EF,FG,GH,HI,IA,AD,DG,GA,CJ,FK,IL$. There is an automorphism of order $3$ which maps $J$ to $K$, but no automorphism swaps $J$ and $K$.

By the way, if we delete the vertex $L$, the resulting graph $\Gamma$ (with $11$ vertices and $14$ edges) is an example of something else: the vertices $J$ and $K$ are not symmetric (the graph $\Gamma$ has no nontrivial automorphism) although the subgraphs $\Gamma-J$ and $\Gamma-K$ are isomorphic.

+1 For an explicit example. You can save a few vertices by removing $J$, $K$ and $L$ and putting diagonals in the squares instead.

20 years ago, the instant that I found out my father had died, the first thing I did was draw an example of a graph with that second property.  I suppose I wasn't ready to deal with the emotional news, so my brain reverted to doing what comes most naturally to it, and solved a maths problem.
